# Configuring tomcat classpath for multiple war files

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

I have multiple war files deployed in my tomcat7. Can you please tell me to how to configure classpath in tomcat so for each application it will look in the respective folder in tomcat for properties files and all.
For example, abc.war and xyz.war files are deployed in webapp folder so for abc.war it will look into /shared/abc/.... and for xyz it will look into /shared/xyz/.... whereas shared folder is in tomcat7 only.

**Note:** I want this because all the war files are using the properties file of same name  so instead of finding and changing in code (which is very hectic) I want that whenever a request comes from abc.war then it should look into /shared/abc... and when the request is from xyz.war then it should look into /shared/xyz/...

Answer (score 1):

you dont have to do anything. For each war file (web application) only its own properties files will be visible.

So place your properties files in the war not in a shared folder or libraries.

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you want to use the same file name (`the_file.properties`) but with different content; otherwise you can reuse it across all applications and you don't really need that "separation".

In that case, you can do something like this (specific to Tomcat):

```
private static final String ROOT_PATH = "catalina.home";
private static final String PROPS_FILE = "the_file.properties";

File directory = new File(System.getProperty(ROOT_PATH), "path/to/props_file");
File propsFile = new File(directory, PROPS_FILE);
BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(propsFile));
```

Comment: You don't need to know the root path. `ServletRequest.getRealPath()` will already do exactly what you've posted here. Accessing it as a resource would be even simpler.